# Change LineBreak Characters from UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel

When i Add let say following text into my UILabel,

```
Lorem, Ipsum, is simply, dummy text of, the printing, and typesetting industry.
```

Now, let say my UILabel's width is limited but number of lines = 0(unlimited), then it will show the text like:

```
Lorem, Ipsum, is
simply, dummy text
of, the printing,
and typesetting 
industry.
```

Here, you can see that line breaks are done at whitespaces, now i want them to update, and i want line breaks only when there is newline or comma(,) is there. So, How can i Implement that.

My Expected output is

```
Lorem, Ipsum,
is simply,
dummy text of,
the printing,
and typesetti
ng industry.
```

Comment: but you add the \n in evrey 14 chars correct

Comment: no, i have fixed width label, so if it is unable to accomodate the given line, then it breaks the line, but breaks should not be at whitespaces as default, it should be only at commas. If it is able to accomodate even commas to single line, then new line should not be added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tested solution**

Create `text` and `customText` empty string

```
let text = "Lorem, Ipsum, is simply, dummy text of, the printing, and typesetting industry."
var customText = ""
```

Populate `customText` by substituting spaces    with non-breakable spaces `\u{00a0}` if previous character is not `,`

```
text.characters.enumerated().forEach { (idx, character) in
    let prevChar = text[text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: max(0, idx-1))]
    if character == " " && prevChar != "," {
        customText.append("\u{00a0}")
    }
    else {
        customText.append(character)
    }
}
```

Create your label and assign customText to its text

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 115, height: 5))
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.text = customText
label.sizeToFit()
```

Comment: It looks pretty well, will try it tommorrow on my machine and will accept the answer if it worked

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *string = @"Lorem, Ipsum,\n is simply,\n dummy text of,\n the printing,\n and typesett\ning industry.";
```

Now use this string

Comment: Here the text that is dynamic text, here i have just provided the sample example.

Comment: then there should be any static, like "," . after that have to move to next line

Comment: I dont require newline at every comma, I required new line if and only if, my fixed width label is not able to accomodate the given words, now if it is required to have new line, then it should be from only comma.

Comment: here in above case see, after lorem, .. there is no newline, but after lorem, ipsum, it added new line, as it cant accomodate "is simply"

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.0

Simply add text like this. I have tested this and here you go with your expected output, but don't forget to set the label height according to this.

```
label33.text = "Lorem Ipsum,\nis simply,\ndummy text of,\nthe printing,\nand typesetti\nng industry."
```

Comment: Here the text that is dynamic text, here i have just provided the sample example.

Comment: you want output like paragraph?

Comment: yes like paragraph, but linebreaks only at comma, if comma not available at nearest point then will break any point where it completes the line

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should subclass the UILabel,CustomLabel.You should calculate the content and commas and add \n。